# Low Side Reverse Protection Diode + Wide Battery Input Range

Tags: batteries, reverse-polarity

**Quick background:**

I'm working on a very wide input range for a battery powered application (capability for two different types of chemistries). In the original design, a low side NFET was used as reverse polarity protection. This works, of course, at higher battery levels but when it starts getting lower, Vgs is just simply not high enough to sustain the in-rush currents from the devices being powered.

So I was able to find a low Iq charge pump from LT and was using it somewhere else in the circuit but I thought.. "why not use it to drive the gate of that low side FET as well!" See what I'm talking about below.

[image: Reverse polarity low side NFET]

So the big question is, any gotchas here that I'm not thinking of? I'm going to have it prototyped up shortly but I figured it would benefit the community if I share my concerns here!

Thanks y'all

Comment: do you have any specs for Vmin max on each port that are relevant?  as well RgsCiss =T issues during transition with high current

Comment: I'd say give it a try. I think it will work. I wonder though, if you quickly connect the circuit in forward, and then reverse polarity if the mosfet will still be on due to the very large 10M resistor.

Comment: Good point @drew

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist  Vmin/max for the Schottky diodes? Left side is either 0 or 5V. Battery+ ranges from about 7.4V down to 1.4V (or less due to high current transients) The Ciss is nearly 600pf so that may not play so nicely with the 10M. I'm just trying to strike a good compromise between static current draw (/battery life) and functionality.

Comment: Heat dissipation is always a factor when bridge two low ESR voltages (battery & supply) at different potentials. I^2ESR

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist heat dissipation though the common cathode Schottky? I would imagine that the instantaneous forward current may be high to charge the gate but otherwise very low due to the 10M to ground. The cathode is only feeding the gate of that low side protection FET. Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As long as Vz+Vf < difference is voltage from Vbat to Vcp, no issue which depends on CP current limit or ESR